# My state isn´t updating in a change handler

Tags: reactjs

I have this function to change a value on my state. I don´t know the reason why the state is the same at the beginning and in the end of the function .

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(state);
        setState(prevState =>  ({
            ...prevState,
            form: {
                ...prevState.form,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
                
            }
        }));
        console.log(state);
      }
```

I have a input field, each time the user  make changes in that field this function should trigger and update the form state

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: data,
    updateModal: false,
    form: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        content: '',
    }
  })
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous and may be batched. This is in the React docs and in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` receives a callback function that updates the state. `console.log` line is executed right after the callback was sent to setState (and not yet executed).

setState has also second parameter, which is called after state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see your updated state executing immediate log.

To see your update state, please consider adding this line of code.

```
useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);
```